# How can I implement an AI-driven conversation system?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I want to implement a conversation system into my RPG (trying to get advanced AI as possible). Conversation as in, the player types:
"Hi, I would like a beer"
and the bartender would respond with
"Coming right up"
and then hand the player a beer.

I've got some ideas and some things I'd like to try, but first I would like to look at what's already been done. But extensive Googling does not turn up anything, so I'm wondering: has this been done or is there research being done in it? (I know this is very complicated, but I'm willing to give it a shot.)

Answer (score 1):

Sure it has.  Have a look at the "[Eliza](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA)" program and its descendants.  There's also a Wiki article on [chatterbots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chatterbot) that might interest you.  Have a look at [AIML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AIML) as a way to represent the rules you might use.

Comment: AIML is too simple for what I want to do, and the chatterbots just fake understanding: "ELIZA's key method of operation (copied by chatbot designers ever since) involves the recognition of cue words or phrases in the input, and the output of corresponding pre-prepared or pre-programmed responses which can move the conversation forward in an apparently meaningful way (e.g. by responding to any input that contains the word 'MOTHER' with 'TELL ME MORE ABOUT YOUR FAMILY')". Can you recommend any literature on this subject?

Comment: Hmmm.  Then I'd start with Searle's "Chinese Room" parable.  There's a lot of literature on this problem, but there's no essential difference between Eliza and what Watson's natural language interface did on Jeopardy.  If you want to have "real understanding" then you'll have to start by defining what real understanding is.

Answer (score 1):

For an advanced design, look up the game "[Façade](http://www.interactivestory.net/)". The game's site describes the technologies used and gives links to relevant papers. There was also recently an extensive article in Gamasutra about this, called [Beyond Façade: Pattern Matching for Natural Language Applications](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/6305/beyond_fa%C3%A7ade_pattern_matching_.php).

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look into the [Turing Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test) and it's relevant scientific following/conferences/publications to see what has been done in the humanizing of AI speech.